# Install nginx module after installation mac osx

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew

I install nginx with the command:
brew install nginx

After I use the module set_real_ip_from in my nginx.conf file:

```
ginx: [emerg] unknown directive "set_real_ip_froxm" in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
```

I need install the module [http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html)

But I not know, I try with this

```
brew reinstall nginx --with-http_realip_module
```

But not works...

How can install a nginx module?

Answer (score 3):

You could use nginx-full. This allows you to include the module you want. Here are the instructions:

```
brew tap homebrew/nginx
brew install nginx-full --with-realip
```

More information in https://github.com/denji/homebrew-nginx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It seems homebrew/nginx deprecated, use denji/nginx instead

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

```
brew install nginx
```

then

```
brew services start nginx
```